# Fix Category Url Filter in Magento 2 Layered Navigation

Tags: magento2, product, category, url, seo

By default in Magento 2, the category links look like this [image: link array]

They lead to ?catId=xxx, instead of the better SEO friendly links, like the product name.

I found a solution for this issue, but it's for magento 1, and it look like this: 
I found this here [solution link](https://www.blueclaw.co.uk/blog/2013/08/12/fix-category-url-filter-in-magento-layered-navigation/)

the orignal code:

```
public function getUrl()
{
    $query = array(
        $this->getFilter()->getRequestVar()=>$this->getValue(),
        Mage::getBlockSingleton('page/html_pager')->getPageVarName() => null // exclude current page from urls
    );
    return Mage::getUrl('*/*/*', array('_current'=>true, '_use_rewrite'=>true, '_query'=>$query));
}
```

and then the custom code to solve the issue:

```
public function getUrl()
{
    if($this->getFilter()->getRequestVar() == "cat"){
        $category_url = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($this->getValue())->getUrl();
        $return = $category_url;
        $request = Mage::getUrl('*/*/*', array('_current'=>true, '_use_rewrite'=>true));
        if(strpos($request,'?') !== false ){
            $query_string = substr($request,strpos($request,'?'));
        }
        else{
            $query_string = '';
        }
        if(!empty($query_string)){
            $return .= $query_string;
        }
        return $return;
    }
    else{
        $query = array(
            $this->getFilter()->getRequestVar()=>$this->getValue(),
            Mage::getBlockSingleton('page/html_pager')->getPageVarName() => null // exclude current page from urls
        );

        return Mage::getUrl('*/*/*', array('_current'=>true, '_use_rewrite'=>true, '_query'=>$query));
    }
}
```

For magento 2, we have the same function in 
`vendor\magento\module-catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\Item.php` we have  **getUrl()** function

Dose anyone know what it's the equivalent code for magento 2?

Answer (score 4):

It's possible you can use this code for magento 2.

For magento 2, we have the same function in  vendor\magento\module-catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\Item.php we have getUrl() function.

the orignal code:

```
public function getUrl()
    {
        $query = [
            $this->getFilter()->getRequestVar() => $this->getValue(),
            // exclude current page from urls
            $this->_htmlPagerBlock->getPageVarName() => null,
        ];
        return $this->_url->getUrl('*/*/*', ['_current' => true, '_use_rewrite' => true, '_query' => $query]);
    }
```

and then the custom code to solve the issue:

```
public function getUrl()
    {
        if($this->getFilter()->getRequestVar() == "cat"){
            $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
            $category_url = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($this->getValue())->getUrl();
            $return = $category_url;
            $request = $this->_url->getUrl('*/*/*', array('_current'=>true, '_use_rewrite'=>true));
            if(strpos($request,'?') !== false ){
                $query_string = substr($request,strpos($request,'?'));
            }
            else{
                $query_string = '';
            }
            if(!empty($query_string)){
                $return .= $query_string;
            }
            return $return;
        }
        else{
            $query = array(
                $this->getFilter()->getRequestVar()=>$this->getValue(),
                $this->_htmlPagerBlock->getPageVarName() => null // exclude current page from urls
            );

            return $this->_url->getUrl('*/*/*', array('_current'=>true, '_use_rewrite'=>true, '_query'=>$query));
        }
    }
```

It's working only category section.
It's working fine in my case.

Comment: working bro thaks